# Change highlight in spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

**PROBLEM**

I've tried to change the select highlight in my application but with no luck.
I've been doing it via styles because I have quite a lot of them in my app.
I would be grateful if you have told me what is wrong with my code.

**CODE**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/MyImgBtn</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/MySpinnerTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MySpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/custom_activated_background</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

So I've managed to merge two selectors with setting style on `setDropDownViewResource` layout element. But what I get at the moment are two selectors appearing at the same time.
I've tried to set `android:dropDownSelector="@android:color/transparent"` on Spinner in XML but still no luck. Posting more code below.

**SPINNER**

```
    final Spinner yearSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yearSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> adapterYear = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.spinner_item_layout , yearsItems);
    yearSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(itemSelectedListener);
    yearSpinner.setAdapter(adapterYear);

   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/yearSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@id/yearTxt"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/podpowiedzi"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >
    </Spinner>
```

**SPINNER_ITEM_LAYOUT**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the style and colours of your spinner drop down items add the following to your style.xml

```
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@style/android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>

</style>
```

And then create the "spinner_selector.xml" in your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/orange" /> <!-- current selected -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/orange_bright" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
</selector>
```

If you want to custom highlight colour when you press on the spinner, we need 9 patch images for spinner backgrounds. Do the following steps:

1) visit this website:http://android-holo-colors.com/, select Spinner, select the colour you want for your spinner highlight and download the zip file. (there are many other options depends on your app)

2) In the zip file open res-->drawable and save file "apptheme_spinner_background_holo_light.xml" to your drawable folder

3) save the following images in the right drawable folders:
apptheme_spinner_default_holo_light.9.png
apptheme_spinner_disabled_holo_light.9.png
apptheme_spinner_focused_holo_light.9.png
apptheme_spinner_pressed_holo_light.9.png

4) add this to your style.xml file:

```
<style name="MySpinnerTheme" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/apptheme_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

In future, you can auto generate any style you want with all the resources required (including spinner highlight colour) thr this website:
http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Thanks mate going to try it out!
How can I change the color of the click on the spinner?

Comment: I've tired your way with spinnerItem but it did now work :C
I still have android 4.2 blue highlight.

Comment: I don't know why its not working with you. just manke sure to add `<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/MySpinnerTheme</item>`. Anyway, I used this code yesterday and updated the spinners in one of my apps and it worked fine. sorry man :(

Comment: It did not work on HTC One either. Maybe the reason is that I use setDropDownViewResource on spinner with custom layout ?

Comment: What I managed to do was merging two selectors with your way. And maybe because mine have high opacity I can see them both appearing. 
I set `style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"` on `setDropDownViewResource` layout resource. But it still ain't what I'm looking for.